# Adding custom table for model in django admin panel

Tags: django

I want to add custom table to my model. I explored this question and found out that I should change change_list_results.html like this:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% render_table table %}
```

Some details.

I implemented table as:

```
class MyModelTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Then I plugged it to TableView:

```
class MyModelTableView(tables.SingleTableView):
    table_class = MyModelTable
    queryset = MyModel.objects.using('my_database').all()
    template_name = "admin/change_list_results.html"
```

After that I redefined url in the head urls.py (that is the error):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'admin/crm/my_model/', MyModelTableView.as_view()
    ),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

So if i define this url like this I can't get anything except table, but if I comment it I get error:

```
ValueError at /admin/crm/my_model/
Expected table or queryset, not str
5    {% render_table table %}
```

Comment: Please add more details. Looks like you have a new model table, and you want that rendered on the admin?

Comment: I're right. I use django-tables2 for table. I added details. Thank you for your attention

Comment: I meaned you're right:)

Answer (score 0):

On the `admin.py` just add your model:

`admin.site.register(MyModelTable)`

This is enough to make it display on admin

Comment: It causes error : TypeError: 'DeclarativeColumnsMetaclass' object is not iterable. I tried to put it before and after admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin) and declare fields in Meta class and i had no changes, error is the same